# How to use setInterval and clearInterval as functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm using setInterval with jQuery to change the position of a background-image onLoad but I want to use it as a function so I can call clearInterval to stop it when an element is clicked and to call the function again when another element is clicked but panRight() isn't working on load.

```
function moveImage() {
var x = 0;
    x-=1;
    $('.bg-img').css('background-position-x', x + 'px');
}

function panRight(){
  setInterval(moveImage(),25);
}

// moveImage onLoad
panRight();

$("#stop-animation").click(function(){
  clearInterval(panRight);
});

$("#start-animation").click(function(){
  panRight();
});
```

The following code works as intended onLoad and is what I'm trying to refactor as functions.

```
$(function(){
  var x = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
      x-=1;
      $('.bg-img').css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
  }, 25);
})
```

Comment: `var panRight = setInterval(moveImage, 25);`, not `function panRight(){setInterval(moveImage(), 25);}`.

Comment: If you click on the tags for setInterval and/or clearInterval, it shows questions with those tags. If you click on "learn more" it shows the tag wiki, which has information about how to use the functions, including links to the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function moveImage() {
    var x = 0;
    x -= 1;
    $('.bg-img').css('background-position-x', x + 'px');
}

var panInterval; // timer id

function panRight() {
  panInterval = setInterval(moveImage, 25);
}

// moveImage onLoad
panRight();

$("#stop-animation").click(function() {
  clearInterval(panInterval);
});

$("#start-animation").click(function() {
  panRight();
});
```

Here `var panInterval` is timer id which get returned whenever we call `setInterval` and which can be use to clear the interval

Comment: Very nice! As well as declaring x outside of the function.